# Try to update JSON information from one site with an image url from last FM

Tags: arrays, json, react-native

I'm fairly new with React Native and struggling a long time with an issue I can't get resolved.

I parse an online JSON file with artist and track information. The only thing the website does NOT provide is an image URL. So i try to parse this one using the lastfm api.

I managed to get the URL from the lastfm API but I'm not sure how i get this effectively rendered besides the rendering of the base JSON.

Tried to re-create the object with the things i need, but i always get stuck parsing it. I always get undefined or function errors.

Below a last attempt (not sure if this is the fully one). I tried  a long time so this might be a mess. Don't shoot me for that haha

```
async initializeNowPlaying () {
await fetch (nowPlayingUrl + showNumberOfTracks)
  .then (response => response.json ())
  .then (responseJson => {
    id = JSON.stringify (responseJson.nowplaying[0].id).replace (/"/g, '');
    title = JSON.stringify (responseJson.nowplaying[0].title).replace (
      /"/g,
      ''
    );
    artist = JSON.stringify (responseJson.nowplaying[0].artist).replace (
      /"/g,
      ''
    );
    dateTime = JSON.stringify (
      responseJson.nowplaying[0].datetime
    ).replace (/"/g, '');
    showName = JSON.stringify (
      responseJson.nowplaying[0].showName
    ).replace (/"/g, '');

    fetch (
      'https://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.getInfo&format=json&api_key=my_key&artist=' +
        this.artist +
        '&track=' +
        this.title
    )
      .then (response => response.json ())
      .then (responseJson => {
        if (responseJson !== 'undefined' || responseJson !== '') {
          albumUrl = responseJson.track.album.image[3]['#text'];
        } else {
          albumUrl = 'https://replacedomain.com/logo.png';
        }
      })
      .catch (error => {
        console.log (
          'Geen afbeelding aanwezig. Standaard afbeelding geretourneerd: ' +
            error
        );
        albumUrl = 'https://replacedomain.com/logo.png';
      });
  });
const obj = {
  id: id,
  datetime: dateTime,
  artist: artist,
  title: title,
  albumUrl: albumUrl,
  showName: 'showName',
};

oldObject = this.state.NowPlaying;
newArray = [obj, ...oldObject];
this.setState ({
  NowPlaying: newArray,
});
```

}

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!!

Comment: Do you have any sample code where the problem is located? See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry for that. I added a sample.

Comment: Good stuff. More detail like you have added will hopefully get you a better answer. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I can see what you are trying to so but there is quite a bit of confusion in your code.

You don't seem to understand the differences between `async/await` and `promises`, this article has a good explanation  https://medium.com/@bluepnume/learn-about-promises-before-you-start-using-async-await-eb148164a9c8

Let's try and refactor your code so it is easier to read and makes more sense. I am using `async/await` as it can make for cleaner and easier to read code instead of using `promises`. It also means that I don't have to worry about global variables and trying to update them from inside a promise, which can get tricky as some code will be run synchronously and other asynchronously. Using `async/await` will mean that the code will wait until the `await` code has completed before executing the next line.

1. First remove all promises and use `async/await`, wrap everything in a `try/catch` as await can throw.
2. Download the nowPlayingResponse and get its json.
3. Get all the variables that you require for the final object, you probably will want some protections here as you are accessing an array that may or may not exist.
4. Download the albumResponse and get its json.
5. Set a default albumUrl and update it if one can be take from the json, perhaps some more protections here rather than just accessing parts of the object.
6. Finally construct the object and update state.
7. In the catch you should handle any errors that you get.

Here is the refactor

```
async initializeNowPlaying () {
  try {
    let nowPlayingResponse = await fetch(nowPlayingUrl + showNumberOfTracks);
    let nowPlayingJson = await nowPlayingResponse.json();

    let id = JSON.stringify(nowPlayingJson.nowplaying[0].id).replace(/"/g, '');
    let title = JSON.stringify(nowPlayingJson.nowplaying[0].title).replace(/"/g,'');
    let artist = JSON.stringify(nowPlayingJson.nowplaying[0].artist).replace(/"/g,'');
    let dateTime = JSON.stringify(nowPlayingJson.nowplaying[0].datetime).replace(/"/g, '');
    let showName = JSON.stringify(nowPlayingJson.nowplaying[0].showName).replace(/"/g, '');

    let albumResponse = await fetch (`https://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.getInfo&format=json&api_key=my_key&artist=${artist}&track=${title}`);
    let albumJson = await albumResponse.json();

    let albumUrl = 'https://replacedomain.com/logo.png';
    if (albumJson !== 'undefined' || albumJson !== '') {
      albumUrl = responseJson.track.album.image[3]['#text'];
    } 

    const obj = {
      id: id,
      datetime: dateTime,
      artist: artist,
      title: title,
      albumUrl: albumUrl,
      showName: 'showName',
    };

    let oldObject = this.state.NowPlaying;
    let newArray = [obj, ...oldObject];
    this.setState ({ NowPlaying: newArray });
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn(err);
  }
}
```

Obviously I cannot test this (as I don't have all the apis, keys etc) so this is really just a guide but it should give you a good idea of how you can get your code to work. I think you will also agree that it is much easier to read and understand what is happening.

#### Downloading all items

It seems from your comment that you actually want to download all the urls for the album images and update the items in your play list. You could use `Promise.all` to allow the multiple requests to execute. **Though this may take quite a bit of time to execute as it will depend on the number of albums that you are trying to download.** You can read more about using `Promise.all` here https://www.taniarascia.com/promise-all-with-async-await/

1. Refactor the code for creating the album object into its own function. It will return/resolve to an album object with the correct album url if the call is successful otherwise the default url.
2. Use a `Promise.all` to loop over the `nowPlayingJson.nowplaying` array this will make each request but it won't finish until all loop has completed and each promise has resolved.
3. Update the setState combining the old nowPLaying with the new.

Here is the new code:

```
async initializeNowPlaying () {
  try {
    let nowPlayingResponse = await fetch (nowPlayingUrl + showNumberOfTracks);
    let nowPlayingJson = await nowPlayingResponse.json();

    let newArray = []
    Promise.all(
      nowPlayingJson.nowplaying.map(async album => {
        const albumObj = await getAlbumObject(album)
        newArray.push(albumObj);
      });
    );

    let oldObject = this.state.NowPlaying;
    newArray = [...newArray, ...oldObject];
    this.setState ({ NowPlaying: newArray });
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn(err);
  }
}

async getAlbumObject (album) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    let id = JSON.stringify(album.id).replace(/"/g, '');
    let title = JSON.stringify(album.title).replace(/"/g,'');
    let artist = JSON.stringify(album.artist).replace(/"/g,'');
    let dateTime = JSON.stringify(album.datetime).replace(/"/g, '');
    let showName = JSON.stringify(album.showName).replace(/"/g, '');
    let albumUrl = 'https://replacedomain.com/logo.png';

    let obj = { id, title, artist, dateTime, showName, albumUrl };

    try {
      let albumResponse = await fetch (`https://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.getInfo&format=json&api_key=my_key&artist=${artist}&track=${title}`);
      let albumJson = await albumResponse.json();
      if (albumJson !== 'undefined' || albumJson !== '') {
        let url = albumJson.track.album.image[3]['#text'];
        if (url) obj.albumUrl = url;
      } 
      resolve(obj);
    } catch (err) {
      resolve(obj);
    }
  })
}
```

Again I can't test this but it should give you an idea on how to do this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and solution. And i see what i’ve missed regarding async. IT seems to work except it takes only the first item in the json instead of all items. I think my overall approach might be wrong?

Comment: It takes the first item in your json because you only access the first item `nowPlayingJson.nowPlaying[0]. It really depends on what you want to do. I imaging tweaking this code to get what you actually want shouldn’t be too difficult.

Comment: True. What i want is itterating over all items and create a new object with the album url added to it so all info is complete to parse in the render

Comment: That's pretty much what my update does. However, it is a lot of heavy lifting that is being done in the app.

Comment: Yes  i saw your answer too late ☺️ i know iT is heavy and that is why i initialize the np and add newer items one by one so it does not go over it again and again as the info changes. I Will try your solution and Will go over your suggested links. Always happy with documentation to learn. Thanks for that

Comment: I tried your solution and it gives me an error on the 
try { 
        let albumResponse = await fetch (
part. As it claims AWAIT is a reserved word. Also, the albums do not get updated, but it returns a default URL though. So i need to tweak it a  little but it is definitely a good starting point :)

Comment: I seem to have missed the `async` word out of the `return new Promise` I have now added it. If the `await fetch` is causing an error then it will just return the default URL., that is the purpose of the `try/catch` around it.

Comment: Yeah, I found that also indeed. That runs fine. It gets the albums now. The only thing I need to figure out now is why some albums get a default image if the value is empty or not exist and others get an empty string and DO return but have no value. I'm comparing the responses to see what happens. Basically, it works perfectly now thanks to you :D

Comment: Yeah, i sure will. Can you clarify one thing though?
I get an empty string on this parse (image # 2) why is that? I tried also as single parse to rule out the possibility the rendering timed out or something, but it gives me an empty string and that is where i'm also filtering on :(

https://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.getInfo&format=json&api_key=c844af37e62a70a6bd05509c61cddba0&artist=Palemiger%20Spatzen&track=La%20Modorra

(sorry for the noob questions *shame*, but i try to learn this)

Comment: You are trying to access `track.album.image[2]['#text']`? if that is the case you are getting an empty string because that is what is there.  I don't see anything in that json that could be classed as an image url.

Comment: The only urls in that json take you to webpages.

Comment: Yes that is correct, but it does not return a default image either (simulator complains about empty string). 
Another example which DOES return a default image and is also empty (although the complete image is missing) is this example: https://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.getInfo&format=json&api_key=c844af37e62a70a6bd05509c61cddba0&artist=Gerard%20Schoonebeek&track=Little%20John

I think i need to filter on existence of the IMAGE thingie i guess?

Comment: You are only checking the full json response exists, not whether the image exists. I think you need to check that the image isn't empty.

Comment: I think so too. Will implement this. I guess that would be not too hard :)
Let you know in a sec

Comment: I added this:

let albumJson = await albumResponse.json ();
        if (albumJson) {
          url = albumJson.track.album.image[2]['#text'];
          if (url > '') {
            obj.albumUrl = albumJson.track.album.image[2]['#text'];
          } else {
            obj.albumUrl = 'https://dummyurl.nl/images/logo.png';
          }
        }

Now it is working as far as i can see :)

Comment: Done. Thanks a lot for your insight and help today. Really appreciate it!

Comment: One final question: how would you structure the app startup to show the newest items as soon as possible without loosing too much processing time? ☺️

Comment: As I don't really know the structure of the application and I have only seen two functions that exist in it, I honestly do not know.